# MySQL select statement involving join

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, left-join

I have two tables, a and b

table a

```
--------------------
|id  |  item       |
--------------------
|1   |  apple      |
--------------------
|2   |  orange     |
--------------------
|3   |  mango      |
--------------------
|4   |  grapes     |
--------------------
|5   |  plum       |
--------------------
|6   |  papaya     |
--------------------
|7   |  banana     |
--------------------
```

table b

```
----------------------------
user_id | item_id | price  |
----------------------------
32      | 3       | 250    |
----------------------------
32      | 6       | 180    |
----------------------------
32      | 2       | 120    |
----------------------------
```

Now I want to join the two tables in MySql so that I get list of all fruits in table a along with their prices as in table b for user 32; something like this:

```
-----------------------------
|id  |  item       |  price  |
-----------------------------
|1   |  apple      |         |
-----------------------------
|2   |  orange     |   120   |
------------------------------
|3   |  mango      |   250   |
------------------------------
|4   |  grapes     |         |
------------------------------
|5   |  plum       |         |
------------------------------
|6   |  papaya     |   180   |
------------------------------
|7   |  banana     |         |
------------------------------
```

The best I could do was this:

```
SELECT      a.id, 
            a.item, 
            b.price 
FROM        a 
INNER JOIN  b   ON  a.id = b.item_id 
WHERE       b.user_id = 32
```

This gives me only the rows whose price have been set, not the ones whose prices have not been set. How do I frame the SQL?

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` and change the `WHERE` to `AND`.

Comment: Use LEFT JOIN, may be you could try [sqlyog](https://goo.gl/OZqkiw) that could aide you in generating queries with Query Builder feature with proper syntax.

Comment: Do not modify the query in your question to match those of the answers.  Doing so removes the original meaning of the question and invalidates all answers already posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [**LEFT OUTER JOIN**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) instead of **INNER JOIN**

Try this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.item, b.price 
FROM a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON a.id = b.item_id AND b.user_id = 32;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a OUTER JOIN instead

```
SELECT a.id, a.item, b.price 
FROM a LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON a.id = b.item_id WHERE b.user_id = 32
```

Comment: If you pass `b.user_id = 32` in where clause then it won't return the rows where price is not available

Comment: The `WHERE b.user_id = 32` portion is reverting the `LEFT JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN`.  This should be in the `ON` clause.

Answer (score -1):

You need a "LEFT" Join to ensure that all records from the left side are returned regardless of a corresponding value on the right side.

```
SELECT a.id, a.item, b.price
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.item_id
WHERE b.user_id = 32
```

Comment: This is still an `INNER JOIN` due to the `WHERE` clause.  That clause should be in the `ON`